# Fpqc-locally constant if and only if étale-locally constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology, group-schemes, descent

Also in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375442/fpqc-locally-constant-if-and-only-if-%C3%A9tale-locally-constant).

---

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be sheave over $S_\mathrm{fpqc}$. We say $\mathcal{F}$ is a fpqc-locally constant sheaf (of finitely generated abelian groups) if there exists a fpqc covering $(S_i\to S)_{i\in I}$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}|_{S_i}$ is a constant sheaf (associated with a finitely generated abelian group).

Clearly if $\mathcal{F}$ is étale-locally constant then $\mathcal{F}$ is fpqc-locally constant as every étale covering is a fpqc covering see [tag 022C](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022C). Is the reverse ture?

I believe the reverse is true because a finite type group scheme over multiplicative type (fpqc-locally dual of constant group scheme associated with finitely generated abelian group) can be trivialised with a finite étale surjective map (stronger than trivializsed by an étale covering).

I think there should be a direct proof showing the fact that "fpqc-locally constant sheaf can be trivialised by an étale covering or even a finite étale surjective map" without mentioning group scheme. Also I'm not sure if the condition of requiring the associated constant set to be finitely generated abelian groups necessary.

Comment: What is your context for wanting to know this? At first glance it seems like a question possibly more appropriate for MathOverflow.

Comment: @TabesBridges I want to use it to deduce the result about multiplicative type group schemes instead of the other around. I will copy it to MO in a minute.

Comment: @ZWu Sorry to sound like a broken record, if this is not useful just ignore it, but isn't this also discussed (or at lesat provided reference with) in the appendix of that paper of Brian I mentioned in your other post?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I saw this statement exactly from that and his reference makes it a corollary of the result of multiplicative group scheme, and I would like to make it the other way around, I believe this fact has a chance of having an independent proof.